# AngularJS First in array after Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

In my controller I can call:

```
$scope.games[0];
```

To access the first item in my games array. Is there a way to do this keeping Filters in mind.

For example I have:

```
filter:search
```

On my repeat, how can I call $scope.list[0]; to equal the first search result?

This has been answered, thank you. I built a cool widget using AngluarJs for Lagged.com, play free online games here: https://lagged.com/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking... Are you wondering how you can tell if you are on the first element in your filter function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done by injecting the filter's dependency into a controller and calling it in code like

```
var filteredArray = filterDependency(arrayToFilter,args);
```

which returns a new, filtered array. Since you are using the "filter" filter (it's a filter whose name is filter), the dependency injection should be `filterFilter`. Your controller should look something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope,filterFilter){
    var filteredArray = [];
    $scope.list = ["abc","def","ghi","abcdefghi"];
    $scope.$watch('search',function(newValue){
       filteredArray = filterFilter($scope.list, newValue);
       // do something with the first result
       console.log(filteredArray[0]); // first result
    });    
});
```

What we're doing is setting a watch on the input model (`search`) so we can get the new value and re-filter the array any time the input is changed.

---

**Also**:

If you need to access the `ng-repeat` index from within the view, you can use the special property `$index` inside of the `ng-repeat` like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter:search">
    {{$index}}
</div>
```

You can also use `$first`, `$middle`, and `$last` [as shown in this Angular doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat).

**Demo**: [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/FHnuC/)

Comment: The first one is the excellent solution. Well thought and a very good solution! However I still dont understand how the 'filterFilter' dependency got there.

Comment: Sorry @Neel I'm just now seeing this comment!  We injected it when defining the controller.  Any filter can be injected this way "[filtername]Filter".  This filter happens to be named "filter" so we injected it via `filterFilter`.  Another random example might inject `dateFilter` or any other.

Answer (score 3):

Not with bracket access. If you have an `ng-repeat` with a filter:

```
ng-repeat="thing in things | filter:search"
```

The filtered list here is kind of anonymous - it doesn't have a name that you can access.

That said, if you take a look at the [docs for ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat), you'll see that inside each repeater's scope, you have access to `$index`, `$first`, `$middle`,  and `$last`.

So something like

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Main">
    <pre ng-repeat="n in nums | filter:isOdd">
        n={{n}}:index={{$index}}:first={{$first}}:middle{{$middle}}:last={{$last}}
    </pre>
</body>
```

Would yield:

```
    n=1:index=0:first=true:middlefalse:last=false

    n=3:index=1:first=false:middletrue:last=false

    n=5:index=2:first=false:middlefalse:last=true
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Qq3/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "ng-repeat"? If so take a look at the properties $first, $index, $middle, and $last. This will allow you to get info on the specific item from the repeat.

For more info check here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat