# Conditionally bind data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have an array of tasks. They have titles and and labels.

```
function Task(taskTitle, taskType) {
  this.title = taskTitle;
  this.type = taskType;
}

$scope.tasks = [];
```

I end up declaring a bunch of tasks with different types and adding them to the array

In my html, I show a column of cards, filtered by type of task:

```
<div ng-model="tasks">
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="abc in tasks track by $index" ng-show="abc.type==0">
    <p> {{ abc.title }} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to bind the first card displayed in this filtered view to some other `div`. I'll be processing an inbox, so I'll whittle this list of cards down to zero. Each time I 'process' a card and remove it from the list, I need the data to refresh.

```
<div ng-model="firstCardInFilteredArray">
  <h4>Title of first card:</h4>
  <p> This should be the title of the first card! </p>
</div>
```

My intuition was to do something like this (in javascript):

```
// pseudo-code!
$scope.inboxTasks = [];
for (i=0; i<tasks.length(); i++) {
  if (tasks[i].type == 0) {
    inboxTasks.append(tasks[i]);
  }
}
```

and somehow run that function again any time the page changes. But that seems ridiculous, and not within the spirit of Angular.

Is there a simple way in pure javascript or with Angular that I can accomplish this conditional binding?

Comment: How about 

    ng-show="abc.type === 0 && $index > 0"

Then, `splice`-ing the first value from the array will cause the binding to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers helped point me in the right direction, but here's how I got it to work:

HTML

```
<input ng-model="inboxEditTitle" />
```

JS

```
$scope.filteredArray = [];
$scope.$watch('tasks',function(){
       $scope.filteredArray = filterFilter($scope.tasks, {type:0});
       $scope.inboxEditTitle = $scope.filteredArray[0].title;
    },true); // the 'true' keyword is the kicker
```

Setting the third argument of `$watch` to `true` means that any changes to any data in my `tasks` array triggers the `watch` function. This is what's known as an *equality watch*, which is apparently more computationally intensive, but is what I need.

[This SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867093/angularjs-first-in-array-after-filter) has helpful commentary on a similar problem, and a great fiddle as well.

[More on different $watch functionality in Angular](http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your ng-repeat: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

```
<div ng-model="tasks">
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="abc in filteredData = (tasks | filter: {type==0}) track by $index">
    <p> {{ abc.title }} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, by saving the filtered data in a separate list you can display the next task like this:

```
<div>
  <h4>Title of first card:</h4>
  <p> filteredData[0].title </p>
</div>
```

Your data will automatically update as you "process" tasks.

Comment: Updated to remove the need for a custom filter

Comment: the inline filtering would work, but how would i go about 'saving' the `filteredData`? Shouldn't this be bound to some object declared in my `$scope`?

Comment: No need to declare it. Angular will initialize the filteredData variable and it will be accessible to your $scope.

Answer (score 0):

To update inboxTasks, you could use `$watchCollection`:

```
$scope.inboxTasks = [];

$scope.$watchCollection('tasks', function(newTasks, oldTasks)
{
   for (i=0; i<newTasks.length(); i++) 
   {
      if(newTasks[i].type == 0) 
      {
         $scope.inboxTasks.append(tasks[i]);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Scott, I might look into that option. What are `newTasks` and `oldTasks` referring to in this code?

Comment: just looked further into it - that's a syntax thing. I was actually able to resolve the issue just using `$watch`.